# How to search for an organization in github via browser

Tags: git, github

Is there a way I can search for an organization (with or, without wildcard) in github via browser? Say, I want to list all the organizations starting with the word "Finance". In reality, unless I know the *exact name of the organization* (e.g., Finance-mydepartment-java) I can not find it via browser. I have to type exactly the name (https://github.com/Finance-mydepartment-java), but it seems I can NOT search with the starting phrase "Finance".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are in the `github.com` page, if you enter your text (verify that the placeholder display `Search Github`, otherwise type the `delete` key once in the search field to search globally), you will be able to find the result in the result tab 'Users' because an `Organization` is seen as a user.

It works well for me...

But if you search 'Finance' on GitHub, you will find a lot of mess ;)

Or you could use the advanced search: https://github.com/search/advanced